# Raspberry pi wget of alamode-setup returns html

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi

Im trying to run the Arduino IDE on the Raspberry pi, this is the code i used to download it

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ wget https://github.com/wyolum/alamode/blob/master/bundles/alamode-setup.tar.gz
```

I run this and the file downloads okay, but if i try to untar it, it returns as this

```
    pi@raspberrypi ~ $ tar xvf alamode-setup.tar.gz
tar:This does not look like a tar file

gzip: stdin: unexpeted end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If i cat the file it retuns html, if there is an easier way to download the Arduino IDE I would love to know

Answer (score 0):

The URL you're trying to get is an HTML page on GitHub.

To get the raw file you need to add ?raw=true to the URL, so...
https://github.com/wyolum/alamode/blob/master/bundles/alamode-setup.tar.gz?raw=true

Since you're grabbing from an https server you'd probably want to add  --no-check-certificate.  So the full command would be:

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/wyolum/alamode/blob/master/bundles/alamode-setup.tar.gz?raw=true
```